# Insert image in a database in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am totally new to Postgres and I have created a database using pgAdmin4. I would like to ask if it is possible to add a column to my table that contains images.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tip: don't save images in the database, save them on the filesystem and save the path of the image in the database in a text column.

However, if you must save an image you should use bytea column (similar to BLOB in other databases). Use the following command to add a bytea column to an existing table:

```
alter table_name add column column_name bytea;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I added the bytea column but now I cannot add images to my column. Isn't the query I have to use : insert into "column_name" values ("image_path") where "id"='image_row'  ??

Comment: insert into table(column_name) values('image_path');

Comment: Please notice, that the insert that I mentioned is inserting the image_path and not the image itself..

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
You can create table with column type as `bytea`.

Using:

`insert into images(image_name, image_raw) values('image.png', bytea('D:\image.jpg'));`

Long answer:
[Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)